# Am doing something wrong of Java 8 fails to do type inference for varargs?

Tags: java, generics, types, casting, builder

I know there are some type-inference related questions already but it seems I found something new.

So I have a simple system of several actions I want to run and builders for them:

Package `foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions` contains:

An interface:

```java
package foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions;

public interface Action {
    void perform();
}
```

An abstract action which doesn't implement an interface and it is *package-private*:

```java
package foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions;

class AbstractAction {
    private final int foo;

    AbstractAction(int foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    int getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

And then I have couple actions,

Action Foo:

```java
package foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions;

public class FooAction extends AbstractAction implements Action {
    public FooAction(int foo) {
        super(foo);
    }

    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Hello from foo!");
    }
}
```

And action Bar:

```java
package foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions;

public class BarAction extends AbstractAction implements Action {
    private final int bar;

    public BarAction(int foo, int bar) {
        super(foo);
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Hello, from bar with: foo=" + getFoo() + ", and bar=" + bar);
    }
}
```

And in package `foo.bar.buzz.fail` I have a set of builders for those actions. One generic builder and couple builders which are action-specific:

```java
package foo.bar.buzz.fail;

import foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions.Action;
import foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions.BarAction;
import foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions.FooAction;

public class Actions {

    public static FooActionBuilder newFooAction() {
        return new FooActionBuilder();
    }

    public static BarActionBuilder newBarAction() {
        return new BarActionBuilder();
    }

    public static class FooActionBuilder extends AbstractActionBuilder<FooActionBuilder, FooAction> {
        @Override
        public FooAction build() {
            return new FooAction(foo);
        }
    }

    public static class BarActionBuilder extends AbstractActionBuilder<BarActionBuilder, BarAction> {
        private int bar;

        @Override
        public BarAction build() {
            return new BarAction(foo, bar);
        }

        public BarActionBuilder withBar(int bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static abstract class AbstractActionBuilder<T extends AbstractActionBuilder, R extends Action> {
        protected int foo;

        public T withFoo(int foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
            return (T) this;
        }

        public abstract R build();
    }
}
```

And then I'm trying to flat map set of actions for a number of seeds in the same `foo.bar.buzz.fail` package:

```java
package foo.bar.buzz.fail;

import foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions.Action;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static foo.bar.buzz.fail.Actions.newBarAction;
import static foo.bar.buzz.fail.Actions.newFooAction;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class App {

    public static Integer[] seeds = {
            1, 2, 3
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Collection<Action> actions = Arrays.stream(seeds)
                .flatMap((foo) -> Stream.of(
                        newFooAction()
                                .withFoo(foo)
                                .build(),
                        newBarAction()
                                .withFoo(foo)
                                .withBar(getBar(foo))
                                .build()))
                .collect(toList());

        for(Action action: actions) {
            action.perform();
        }
    }

    private static int getBar(int foo) {
        return foo * foo;
    }
}
```

My problem being is that it fails to compile with error message:

"Error:(18, 25) java: incompatible types: formal varargs element type foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions.AbstractAction&foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions.Action is not accessible from class foo.bar.buzz.fail.App"

So it seems that compiler things that I'm passing `AbstractAction` classes to varargs methods when it should think of `Action`.
Am I being crazy here or does it look like a compiler bug?

**Notes**:

- If at least one item of varargs is an `Action` explicitly then it works (I can cast one of parameters or just use an anonymous instance of the `Action` interface).
- If I pull the varargs call out of flat map then it works.
- Obviously, if I make `AbstractAction` public it works.
- If I change builders to return `Action` instead of children types then it works.
- I didn't try it on Java 9 and I don't really want to - I'm targeting Java 8 anyway.

Package/classes layout is as follows:

```
foo.bar.buzz.fail ->
    Actions.java
    App.java

foo.bar.buzz.fail.actions ->
    Action.java
    AbstractAction.java
    BarAction.java
    FooAction.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit type parameter:

```
.flatMap((foo) -> Stream.<Action> of(
```

The fact that it *does* work outside of the lambda seems to be an error in Eclipse, since javac still rejects it. I filed this as [Eclipse Bug 530915](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=530915), which has more details.